# Trying to convert mysql to mysqli, not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code, it was originally in mysql() but since it's deprecated and obsolete well i decided to change. Something is clearly not working because when I execute it always says incorrect password/username although it is correct. Database works. Triple checked. Pardon me, i'm a noob at php. here:

```
<?php
//If the user is logged, we log him out
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    //We log him out by deleting the username and userid sessions
    unset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['userid']);
?>
<div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out securely.</div>
<?php
}
else
{
    $ousername = '';
    //We check if the form has been sent
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
    {
        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
$escapePass = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$escapeUser = $_POST['username'];
            $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapePass);
            $password = sha1(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
        }
        else
        {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapeUser);
            $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
        }
        //We get the password of the user
$query = 'SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE username="'.$username.'" ';
        $req = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $dn = mysqli_fetch_array($req);
print $reg;
        //We compare the submited password and the real one, and we check if the user exists
        if($dn['password']==$password and mysqli_num_rows($req)>0)
        {
            //If the password is good, we dont show the form
            $form = false;
            //We save the user name in the session username and the user Id in the session userid
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
?>
```

@Fred -ii- This:

```
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
$escapePass = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$escapeUser = $_POST['username'];
$passescape = sha1($_POST['password']);
$passescape2 = sha1(stripslashes($_POST['password']));
            $ousername = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapePass);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $passescape2);
        }
        else
        {
            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $escapeUser);
            $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $passescape);
        }
```

Comment: Far as I can tell, you're passing `$link` for your `username` but not your `password`

Comment: You need to pare down your code to the bare minimum of what you're having trouble with, and specify exactly *what the problem is* with error messages and clearly indicate the lines to which the errors refer.

Comment: Why don't you switch to using Object Oriented PHP so you don't have to do all that extra typing?

Comment: @Fred-ii- so I just need to do a real escape for $password?

Comment: I prefer manual work.

Comment: Try it out, it should work. I use a similar method, and if I don't pass DB connection to it, it will reject it.

Comment: I guess you like slower code too. LOL

Comment: I have no choice on one the servers I maintain. @PHPglue if it were up to me (on that particular server), I would use PDO ;-) which I do on others I maintain. So it's always good to know (and remember) the older stuff/methods.

Comment: Nope doesn't work. @Fred-ii-

Comment: What's the exact syntax that you're using?

Comment: Check the post @Fred-ii- updated

Comment: Was the password originally created using `sha1`? and did you happen to use `salt` also?

Comment: input plain text, convert to sha, store, login with sha, it worked before with mysql()

Comment: That won't work then. Its encrypted with `sha1`, try removing `sha1` from your code.

Comment: Ok hold on. I'm confused. When the password was `created` and not `inputted`, was `sha1` used?

Comment: no. when you input in signup it converts. it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try this `$query = 'SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE username="'.$username.'" AND password=SHA1('$password')';`

Comment: Syntax Error, unexpected variable

Comment: If you're up to using a somewhat different system yet still using `mysqli_`, have a look at entry `#10` on this page, which works marvels => http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=43257 I have used that in the past with success, plus it adds `salt` and `crypt` which is a bit more safer.

Comment: it has to be mysqli without oop, client requires

Comment: ok let's start from the beggining again.

Comment: Try this from what you added `$passescape = $_POST['password'];` and after `$password = sha1(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $passescape));`

Comment: You could also try `$password = trim(sha1($_POST['password']));` that's about all I can come up with.

Comment: Another thing I noticed that I didn't see was `session_start();` anywhere, since you're using sessions. If you don't have it, put it on top of all your files used. That may very well be one of the big factors at play.

Comment: config.php is in the included file, this is just a fragment of the code,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for a quick **testing** purpose, try this below which is a bare bones method.

You can then slowly build up sanitizing and troubleshoot from thereon.

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$link = mysqli_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');

$query = "SELECT password, id FROM users 
WHERE username = '$username' AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1) 
{
echo 'Sorry, your username and/or password was incorrect.';
}

else
{
echo "Welcome!";
}
?>
```

**Footnote:** I noticed in your original code that you are using sessions.

I did not see `session_start();` in your code, nor any mention of it.

This needs to be at the top of your code and inside **all** your files used,
which will be needed in order to access anything currently in $_SESSION

More on sessions can be found on the PHP.net Website.

- **http://www.php.net/session_start**

Comment: session_start is in my config.php.

Comment: Ok thanks. Did you try my example above? @user2624486

Comment: That's great news! Did you want us to close the question and mark it as answered? If so, you can click the white checkmark till it turns green next to my answer, otherwise it will remain in the unanswered category. @user2624486 Cheers :)

Comment: Yet, do re-test it again while using a bad password, see if it will return an error. @user2624486

Comment: I did, tested on both when I posted that comment.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Now keep a copy of it, then slowly build it up with another copy of the code until you get it to work like you had. Slowly add on, test it, then if and when you get an error, you will know exactly what happened. You can always revert to the original (working) copy. @user2624486 Cheers

Comment: I got it to work with the original script. I fixed some variables and it worked! Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: Right on, that's even better news! @user2624486 thanks for keeping me posted, cheers and you're welcome.